# Why is my question "subjective and likely to be closed"?

Tags: support, subjective-questions

When posting a question recently, I filled in the title field as follows:

> Can you Shift, or move your speed, while Sqeezing?

Immediately after moving off the title field, I got the following red flag beneath it:

> The question you're asking appears subjective and is likely to be closed.

Why did this occur?
Is it a bug?
Is it a new feature?
By what qualities is it judging my question as "subjective"?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Because it contains the word `your`.  The subjective filter is a simple regex, as Jeff states [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4371/how-does-the-automatic-subjective-filter-work).

Answer (score 6):

It's not a sophisticated thing; mostly it was an effort to prevent subjective questions containing things like "what's the best.." and "what's the worst.."

I created the regex by studying a bunch of subjective closed questions; many of them contained the word "your".

It's possible this has outlived its usefulness, or maybe I can tighten it up by just checking for best/worst etc.

Comment: Also, the subjectivity line is a little farther out here.  Maybe a customizable regex per site?

Comment: @C.Ross is right.  The subjectivity line at RPG is a lot wider than at, say, Server Fault, and will definitely have different keywords.  That's going to become even more so if sites like Atheism or Social Engineering go online.

Comment: @CRoss, @Tynam It doesn't have to be perfect - it's not closing your question, just giving you a heads up.  Even though we allow a bit more subjectivity here, you should probably still be advised if you're getting closer to that line.  If they don't have built in site specific support I don't think it's worth doing work to implement in this case.