# Why would this question be closed for being subjective?

Tags: support, subjective-questions

So, I tried writing a question with the title: "What's the point of risk, or the advantage of avoiding death, in games that let you return at the same level?"

And as soon as I moved my cursor to the text editor, I got the warning:

"The question you're asking appears subjective and is likely to be closed."

Wow. What algorithm is sure enough to say that, and why? Is it accurate? I suddenly no longer feel like detailing my interesting question.

Is it just because it has the words "what's the point" in it?

Edit: Ok, I see this sub-part of my question is already asked here: [Why is my question "subjective and likely to be closed"?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/728/why-is-my-question-subjective-and-likely-to-be-closed) and mostly answered by this: [How does the automatic subjective filter work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4371/how-does-the-automatic-subjective-filter-work) - so it's the word "you" - ok...

I am quite interested in hearing what players think about risk of death in games where if you die, the GM lets you get a replacement character at the same power level you were at. This seems to be a common way people play, and I am really interested to hear what such players think.

Is the problem that there is no one right answer, and so this site just doesn't want that kind of question? Do I need to take this to an RPG forum somewhere else? Any suggestions for a good RPG forum?

Comment: For a forum rec: This is one of those question that really needs a good scrum to learn anything about, since you're basically wanting a pile of people's thoughts and opinions on the subject. For that, yeah, a forum is the way to go. If it were me, I'd post in [RPG.net's Tabletop Roleplaying Open subforum](http://forum.rpg.net/forumdisplay.php?3-Tabletop-Roleplaying-Open) (unless you end up making it mostly about D&D(s), then it should go in the d20 subforum, but I don't advise that—many would probably see it as an attack on their favourite D&D edition and dogpile you. TRO is more civil).

Comment: +1 Hehe. Thanks very much for the forum recommendation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Automated warning aside (it's a bit trigger-happy sometimes), it sounds like you'd find a back-and-forth conversation on this topic more fulfilling than the Q&A format the main Stack Exchange site supports. That is, I think the question *could* be framed so it's appropriate for the Stack, but it'd probably not be the kind of question you want to ask anymore.

This is the sort of thing that the [RPG.SE chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/rpg-general-chat) would probably love to discuss, and the people there can probably help you find suitable forums as well.

Comment: +1 the warning is just an algorithm - but in this case it sounds like it may be on target. I don't hear a problem you need to solve, it more sounds like you want to bat the general topic back and forth with folks, which isn't a fit for the format.

Comment: Well I actually do have a question, but there is no one answer to the question. I could also phrase it as something like, "If I have players are expecting not to lose any characters or even character abilities to misadventure or the natural risks of playing with swords in a realistic game system, what can I do to understand and host games for them that will be positive experiences..." but ya, I am really interested in what everyone would say about my actual question.

Comment: @Dronz Yeah, it's not that we don't think you have a question--it's a great topic, which we've already talked about a little in chat!--just that Stack Exchange isn't designed to support it because other places like chats and forums already do that.

Comment: @Dronz I think there is a way to ask that question such that it'd fit here, as there is also a game design angle on the issue. You'd have to think about it pretty carefully to ask it, so it'd be easier to ask it on a forum, but I can see how it'd be possible to ask something in the same vein here.